# Multi-page Static Website to PDF/CHM/Other Converter

Tags: pdf, html, chm

I have several small static websites that I want to turn into PDFs, CHMs, or a similar format. These websites are documentation generated by Ruby's RDoc tool. They have an index.html file and links to other static files all contained in directories up to two-levels deep.

I want to be able to view these docs on my iOS and Android devices. Neither of those devices will let me easily browse a static website so I think a better solution would be to turn these sites into a more supported format on my Ubuntu desktop and then transfer them to something portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give a try to **htmldoc**. htmldoc will help you to convert html source files into html, postscript, or pdf

To install htmldoc use

```
sudo apt-get install htmldoc
```

You can provide a list of files/URLs as input that can be converted to PDF.

[image]

Comment: any idea why htmldoc `v1.8.29` doesn't offer a GUI ?